# Angular 2 ngModel compare old and new value

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

So I've been playing around with Angular 2 for a while now. Using the `[(ngModel)]` directive in an `<input>` is pretty simply. Yet I can't figure out how to pass or at least get the previous value so I can compare both - the new and old one.

I'm getting the change detection through `(ngModelChange)` since `(change)` fired up after bluring out of the input field (seems to be a bug btw). So my code currently looks like this (`$event` could be seen as a placeholder, since I've no idea what to pass in).

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myModel" (ngModelChange)="changeEvent($event)">
```

I've also tried passing in a custom local template variable like so, which obviously didn't work as well:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myModel" #myModel="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="changeEvent($event)">
```

I know, there's at least a possibility to achieve this by using [DoCheck](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html). But since I just need that for a single time (currently) I really don't want to use that method. On top of that I'm using the above construct inside of an `*ngFor`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following:

HTML Template:
`[(ngModel)]="myModel" #model (change)="changeEvent(model.value)"`

Javascript handler:

```
changeEvent(newValue) {
  console.log(newValue, this.myModel);
}
```

The console will log:

`<newValue>, <oldValue>`

Comment: I can't test that right now and so I also can't tell if it's working or not. The main problem in here, which I obviously forgot in my question, is that I'm using this markup inside of an `*ngFor`. Since you're example is accessing `myModel` through `this` it won't work.

Comment: Just pass the loop index to the change function in order to retrieve the old value in your array

Comment: Thanks so far, your solution seems to be working properly. Unfortunately this approach doesn't fit into my use case.

Comment: @Piou can you please suggest, what has to be initial value of myModel, as I am getting undefined or newValue in this.myModel